# shopify application charge failing to save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, shopify-app

Below is my code for a Shopify one-time-application-charge in Ruby. I followed the shopify "add billing to your app" page (https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/adding-billing-to-your-app) for the code, except didn't need a recurring charge. I have also found someone else who posted their one-time-charge code which looks very similar to mine (https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/one-time-application-charge-example-for-shopify-rails-app-489347).

```
def create_application_charge

       application_charge = ShopifyAPI::ApplicationCharge.new(
            name: "MyApp",
            price: 0.09,
            return_url: "https:\/\/myapp.herokuapp.com\/activatecharge",
            test: true)
        save = application_charge.save
        if save
            redirect application_charge.confirmation_url
            return
        end
        flash[:error] = "The save worked: #{save}"
    end
```

The flash always responds as false. Is there a failure at authentication that would prevent this? Or something to get the store to accept an application charge? I'm at a loss as to why this does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: When you run the following in a rails console what is the response?

`application_charge = ShopifyAPI::ApplicationCharge.new(
            name: "MyApp",
            price: 0.09,
            return_url: "https:\/\/myapp.herokuapp.com\/activatecharge",
            test: true)
        save = application_charge.save`

Comment: Using "rails c" and then pasting the above produces: "NoMethodError: undefined method 'path' for nil:NilClass" in 'new'. I guess I need to look into why the ShopifyAPI::ApplicationCharge doesn't work.

Comment: Removing the arguments from the .new and more closely copying the second link I posted above instead causes an ArgumentError: Missing site URI on the save action, where it previously errored on the .new. I assumed this was due to not having a session in the console, but making the same changes in the app and running it still fails to save (without direct error printed to logs).

Comment: Just curious, do the backslashes have to be escaped in the return_url argument, and if not, have you tried without them?

Comment: Do other shopify calls work in the console or does ShopifyAPI need to be included first?

Comment: Other Shopify calls work fine, I'm able to do Theme edits in another part of the app if I bypass the app_charge part while testing. I have not tried without the backslashes and imagine them necessary, but will check and return.

Comment: There appears to be no change, the save still fails. However, the second link I mentioned (the ecommerce one) has a url without the backslashes, so  it may actually be the better thing.

Comment: OH; I completely read right over that you asked "in the console". No, I get NoMethodErrors, most likely due to lack of a session which I don't know how to create in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary issue appears to be that the minimum charge you can request is $0.50, for which I wasn't meeting with my choice of using $0.09 for my test.